# zepto js - simple toggle not working

Tags: jquery, zepto

I am using zepto (http://zeptojs.com/) for a mobile site (I am used to using jQuery on desktop environment).

I have the following code (tweaked slightly so it works on desktop)

```
(function($) {
    // only do this if not on a touch device
    if (!('ontouchend' in window)) {
        $(document).delegate('.filter h2', 'click', function(e) {
            $('.filter div').toggle();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
})(window.Zepto);
```

However the toggle isnt working. If I replace that line with a standard `alert('hello world');` it gets picked up (so I know the js is being called).

Any idea what I am missing?

Cheers,
Ad.

**EDIT
I seem to get this error:
Timestamp: 02/04/2012 15:02:35
Error: h.body.insertAdjacentElement is not a function
Source File: file:/js/zepto.min.js
Line: 1**

Answer (score 1):

You've got it mostly right. You have mixed up the order of the function arguments. The `delegate` function is deprecated so you should use `on` instead too.

Replace this:

```
$(document).delegate('.filter h2', 'click', function(e) {
```

with this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.filter h2', function(e) {
```